# How can I rename a file name in J language?

Tags: j

I want to change a file's name from test.csv  to new.csv, but I can't find it how

Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `files.ijs` (automatically loaded)

```
'newname' frename 'oldname'
```

**or**

Using OS command with `shell`:

```
 shell'mv oldname newname'
```

There are also some other ways but, I think, most are deprecated.